# Set read cursor fails

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost to read a file
But when I set `seekg` to a position (~20000) in the file, 
I get a runtime error

```
Microsoft C++ exception:
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl`<`boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector`<`std::ios_base::failure>>> at memory location 0x00EEC874.
```

Code:

```
ifstream if("file.bin",std::ios::binary)
if (if.is_open())
{       
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source>is(fs);
    is.seekg(20000, is.beg);  //error is here

    ////    read
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code shouldn't compile. If it does, file a bug report with the compiler vendor.

`if` is a reserved keyword.

Assuming you messed up the code sample, (because you also had missing `;`), it should just work but you may just have missing files/error handling:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c079832d26442c3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("main.cpp",std::ios::binary);
    if (ifs.is_open())
    {       
        boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source> is("main.cpp");
        if (is.seekg(200, is.beg))
            std::cout << is.rdbuf();
    }
}
```